# ラジオボタンで選択したデータが意図した通り受け取れない

Tags: php, mysql

ウェブサイトを作る一貫で、HTMLのフォーム内にラジオボタンを設置しました。
今回はオブジェクト指向で作ることが前提で
HTML→userAction→functionのフローで実行するようにしています。
btnSubmitを押すと、sqlのusersテーブルにデータが格納され、ログインページへ移行する
というコードです。

ラジオボタンで４つ選択肢を作ったのですが、先頭の・A　ボタンを選択した時しかPHPMyAdminに取得されません。
B, C, D を選択したときはデータ格納されず、、、
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

以下コード抜粋です。

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="a"> A <br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="b"> B <br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="c"> C <br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="d"> D <br><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-dark ">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**userAction**

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];

    $user->createUser($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

**function**

```
function createUser($a, $b, $c, $d){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (a, b, c, d) VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d')";

    if($this->conn->query($sql)){
        header("location: forms/login.php");
    }else{
        die("Error: " . $this->conn->error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML のラジオボタンで `name="course"` と指定しているので、PHP で受け取る際は `$_POST["course"]` を参照する必要があると思います。
また、ラジオボタンなので選択肢は常に一つですから、値を取り出すには例えば以下のような記載になるでしょう。

```php
if(isset($_POST["course"])){
    $course = $_POST["course"];
}
```

参考:
[ラジオボタンの値を取得 » php実験室](http://www.weblaboratory.jp/WP/phptrial/2011/07/09/sec06/)